# ReadLine eats up tilde

Tags: c#, console, readline

I was doing a small test program for a job I'm working on when I noticed something odd. Take the following snippet:

```
string words;
while ((words = Console.ReadLine()) != "quit")
{
    Console.WriteLine(words);
}
```

If i type anything with a `tilde` it get's eaten up. So if i type `ação`, it writes back `açao`.

Anyone can explain why? All other accents work fiene.

Comment: Support for characters outside your current OEM character set is "interesting" with Window's console subsystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like an encoding issue, try changing input/output encoding to unicode:

```
Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
string words;
while ((words = Console.ReadLine()) != "quit")
{
    Console.WriteLine(words);
}
```